# Dynamically set the width and height of SVG based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dynamic, bootstrap-modal

Firstly, I'm using jQuery-3.2.1 and bootstrap-3.3.7 and can't change this.

My basic objective is to launch a bootstrap modal and display a dynamic Gantt chart in this modal. I say dynamic as the number of items to display in the chart as well as the timescale can and will differ from time to time. My problem is that I don't know how to achieve the dynamic aspect and end up having to define the height and the width of the SVG that displays in the modal. This then means that if the number of items charted is greater than the height of the SVG, those items won't be visible in the chart. Similarly, the x-axis renders with minimum distance between the ticks/gridlines, making it near impossible to read the chart.

What I've done so far:

I found a nice looking chart at the following link [D3 v4 Gantt Chart](https://codepen.io/mcolynuck/pen/gxJerq) and used this with some minor modifications to reverse the timescale so that it goes from left to right displaying most recent to oldest event.

I have a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal72/nqvtmugL/17/) , see screenshot below showing how cramped the ticks are and how difficult it is to read the timeline with the width and the height defined in code

```
var w = 650;
var h = 450;
var svg = d3.selectAll("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("class", "svg");
```

[image: Gantt Chart]

How can I define the SVG and modal so that the ticks/gridlines of the x-axis remains readable when the difference between the smallest and the largest dates blows out? Do I have to check the number of days between and then use this to specify a width or how else can it be achieved? Similarly with the height, do I have to check the number of categories and use this number to determine the height of the SVG that needs to be set or is there another way of achieving this?

Finally, as you'll notice in the fiddle, the tooltip on hover on the items in the chart do not at all align with where they're supposed to display. I saw a tip somewhere about seting isSVG to false in the bootstrap.min.js file but that had no effect.

Any help with this would be much appreciated - also, more than happy to elaborate further if needed but am hoping the fiddle will illustrate the problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to adapt the ticks count to the width, not the other way around (more on that below). That being the case, instead of using an interval, like `d3.timeDay`, just set the (approximate) number of ticks:

```
axis.ticks(10)
```

However, if in fact you want to modify the width of the SVG, you can count the number of days and set the SVG width accordingly:

```
var dayWidth = 30;//set the width for each day here
var numberOfDays = d3.timeDay.count(timeScale.domain()[0], timeScale.domain()[1]);//get the total number of days in the data
w = numberOfDays * dayWidth;
svg.attr("width", w);
```

This is just a quick code for you to see how you can do it, a better solution sets the margins accordingly (I didn't do it because you have lots of magical numbers in your code).

Regarding the height, you can calculate it based on the number of tasks, and set the SVG accordingly:

```
h = tasks.length * gap + topPadding + 40;
svg.attr("height", h);
```

Bear in mind that you still have magic numbers here. Try to avoid them.

Here is the code with those change:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  myObj = JSON.parse('{"QUAL":[{"task": "milk", "type": "Ordered", "startTime": "14/10", "endTime": "16/11"},{"task": "butter", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "22/09", "endTime": "23/09"},{"task": "butter", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "24/09", "endTime": "25/09"},{"task": "bread", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "04/10", "endTime": "15/10"},{"task": "water", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "11/10", "endTime": "16/10"},{"task": "fish", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "21/09", "endTime": "23/09"},{"task": "mince", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "26/09", "endTime": "27/09"},{"task": "soda", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "04/10", "endTime": "08/10"},{"task": "sugar", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "04/10", "endTime": "08/10"},{"task": "flour", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "09/10", "endTime": "11/10"},{"task": "shampoo", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "10/10", "endTime": "11/10"},{"task": "salt", "type": "On Hold", "startTime": "04/10", "endTime": "04/10"}]}')



  myObj2 = JSON.parse('{"QUAL":[{"task": "milk", "type": "Ordered", "startTime": "14/10", "endTime": "16/11"},{"task": "butter", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "22/09", "endTime": "23/09"},{"task": "butter", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "24/09", "endTime": "25/09"},{"task": "bread", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "04/10", "endTime": "15/10"},{"task": "water", "type": "Completed", "startTime": "11/10", "endTime": "16/10"},{"task": "fish", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "21/09", "endTime": "23/09"},{"task": "mince", "type": "Discontinued", "startTime": "26/09", "endTime": "27/09"}]}')


  var taskArray = [];


  $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {

    document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = ""
    taskArray = [];

  });


  $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {

  });



  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

    $.each(myObj.QUAL, function(i, j) {
      taskArray.push({
        task: j.task,
        type: j.type,
        startTime: j.startTime,
        endTime: j.endTime
      })
    })
    makeChart();
  });


  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {



    $.each(myObj2.QUAL, function(i, j) {
      taskArray.push({
        task: j.task,
        type: j.type,
        startTime: j.startTime,
        endTime: j.endTime
      })
    })
    makeChart();
  });

  makeChart = function() {


    var w,
      h,
      dayWidth = 30;

    $('#amsModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static'
    });
    // $('#amsDetailBodyImage').css('display', 'none');

    var svg = d3.selectAll("#chart")
      //.selectAll("svg")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("class", "svg");

    //var dateFormat = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
    var dateFormat = d3.timeParse("%d/%m");

    var timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([d3.min(taskArray, function(d) {
          return dateFormat(d.startTime);
        }),
        d3.max(taskArray, function(d) {
          return dateFormat(d.endTime);
        })
      ]);

    var numberOfDays = d3.timeDay.count(timeScale.domain()[0], timeScale.domain()[1]);

    w = numberOfDays * dayWidth;

    svg.attr("width", w);

    timeScale.range([w - 150, 0]);

    var categories = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
      categories.push(taskArray[i].type);
    }

    var catsUnfiltered = categories; //for vert labels

    categories = checkUnique(categories);

    makeGant(taskArray, w);

    var title = svg.append("text")
      .text("Groceries")
      .attr("x", w / 2)
      .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-size", 18)
      .attr("fill", "#000000");



    function makeGant(tasks, pageWidth) {

      var barHeight = 20;
      var gap = barHeight + 4;
      var topPadding = 75;
      var sidePadding = 75;

      h = tasks.length * gap + topPadding + 40;
      svg.attr("height", h);

      var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, categories.length])
        .range(["#00B9FA", "#F95002"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

      makeGrid(sidePadding, topPadding, pageWidth, h);
      drawRects(tasks, gap, topPadding, sidePadding, barHeight, colorScale, pageWidth, h);
      vertLabels(gap, topPadding, sidePadding, barHeight, colorScale);


      //$('.modal-button').attr('disabled', true);
    }


    function drawRects(theArray, theGap, theTopPad, theSidePad, theBarHeight, theColorScale, w, h) {

      var bigRects = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(theArray)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * theGap + theTopPad - 2;
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return w - theSidePad / 2;
        })
        .attr("height", theGap)
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            if (d.type == categories[i]) {
              return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
            }
          }
        })
        .attr("opacity", 0.2);


      var rectangles = svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(theArray)
        .enter();


      var innerRects = rectangles.append("rect")
        .attr("rx", 3)
        .attr("ry", 3)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          // return timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)) + theSidePad;
          return timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime)) + theSidePad;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * theGap + theTopPad;
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          //return (timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime))-timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)));
          return (timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)) - timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime)));
        })
        .attr("height", theBarHeight)
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            if (d.type == categories[i]) {
              return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
            }
          }
        })


      var rectText = rectangles.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.task;
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return (timeScale(dateFormat(d.endTime)) - timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime))) / 2 + timeScale(dateFormat(d.startTime)) + theSidePad;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * theGap + 14 + theTopPad;
        })
        .attr("font-size", 11)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("text-height", theBarHeight)
        .attr("fill", "#000000");


      rectText.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        // console.log(this.x.animVal.getItem(this));
        var tag = "";

        if (d3.select(this).data()[0].details != undefined) {
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" +
            "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" +
            "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" +
            "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime + "<br/>" +
            "Details: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].details;
        } else {
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" +
            "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" +
            "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" +
            "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime;
        }
        var output = document.getElementById("tag");

        var x = this.x.animVal.getItem(this) + "px";
        var y = this.y.animVal.getItem(this) + 25 + "px";

        output.innerHTML = tag;
        output.style.top = y;
        output.style.left = x;
        output.style.display = "block";
      }).on('mouseout', function() {
        var output = document.getElementById("tag");
        output.style.display = "none";
      });


      innerRects.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        var tag = "";

        if (d3.select(this).data()[0].details != undefined) {
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" +
            "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" +
            "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" +
            "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime + "<br/>" +
            "Details: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].details;
        } else {
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" +
            "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" +
            "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" +
            "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime;
        }
        var output = document.getElementById("tag");

        var x = (this.x.animVal.value + this.width.animVal.value / 2) + "px";
        var y = this.y.animVal.value + 25 + "px";

        output.innerHTML = tag;
        output.style.top = y;
        output.style.left = x;
        output.style.display = "block";
      }).on('mouseout', function() {
        var output = document.getElementById("tag");
        output.style.display = "none";

      });
    }


    function makeGrid(theSidePad, theTopPad, w, h) {

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(timeScale)
        .ticks(d3.timeDay, 1)
        .tickSize(-h + theTopPad + 20, 0, 0)
        //   .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d %b'));
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d/%m'));
      var grid = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grid')
        //   .attr('transform', 'translate(' +theSidePad + ', ' + (h - 50) + ')')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + theSidePad + ', ' + (h - 20) + ')')
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "#000000")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("font-size", 10)
        //       .attr("dy", "1em")
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

    }

    function vertLabels(theGap, theTopPad, theSidePad, theBarHeight, theColorScale) {
      var numOccurances = new Array();
      var prevGap = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        numOccurances[i] = [categories[i], getCount(categories[i], catsUnfiltered)];
      }

      var axisText = svg.append("g") //without doing this, impossible to put grid lines behind text
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(numOccurances)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          if (i > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
              prevGap += numOccurances[i - 1][1];
              // console.log(prevGap);
              return d[1] * theGap / 2 + prevGap * theGap + theTopPad;
            }
          } else {
            return d[1] * theGap / 2 + theTopPad;
          }
        })
        .attr("font-size", 11)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("text-height", 14)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            if (d[0] == categories[i]) {
              //  console.log("true!");
              return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i)).darker();
            }
          }
        });

    }

    //from this stackexchange question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890203/unique-for-arrays-in-javascript
    function checkUnique(arr) {
      var hash = {},
        result = [];
      for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) { //it works with objects! in FF, at least
          hash[arr[i]] = true;
          result.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    //from this stackexchange question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227981/count-how-many-strings-in-an-array-have-duplicates-in-the-same-array
    function getCounts(arr) {
      var i = arr.length, // var to loop over
        obj = {}; // obj to store results
      while (i) obj[arr[--i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1; // count occurrences
      return obj;
    }

    // get specific from everything
    function getCount(word, arr) {
      return getCounts(arr)[word] || 0;
    }

    $('#amsModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static'
    });

  };



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 1000px;*/
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
  #chart {
    /*    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;*/
    overflow: scroll;
    /*position: absolute;*/
  }
  
  .grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.3;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
  
  #tag {
    color: white;
    background: #FA283D;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  
  #tag:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-bottom-color: #FA283D;
    top: -20px;
  }
  
  .container-fluid {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  
  .button {
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  
  .modal-body-detail {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <title>Meh</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="row">

      <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Long
        </button>

      <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Short
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade autoModal " id="amsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="amsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="amsModalLabel">Orders</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div id="detailBody" class="modal-body ">
            <div id="container">
              <div id="chart"></div>
              <!-- chart -->
              <div id="tag"></div>
              <!-- tooltip on hover -->
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary modal-button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply Gerardo, much appreciated. I got a bit sidetracked so haven't had a chance to look at this yet but am really excited about checking this out  before posting back. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to get back to you. That does indeed work a treat, can't thank you enough!