# How to group labels in Timeline chart in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I really need some help. I'm trying to make my own Timeline chart (the same as google timeline). It works already but I can not figure out how to make a function for grouping labels by type. I hardcoded this function and it works for 3 groups/types. What I need is to make a universal function that groups all labels even if there are 100 of them. 
 The second problem is that in the second and third groups are not in the same line if a.endTime >= b.startTime. I will be very thankful for every help 
Here is my code:

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 400;

var svg = d3
  .select(".svg")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("class", "svg");

//main array
var items = [{
    task: "conceptualize",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-1-28", //year/month/day
    endTime: "2013-2-1",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "sketch",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-2-6",
    endTime: "2013-2-9",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "color profiles",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-2-6",
    endTime: "2013-2-9",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "HTML",
    type: "coding",
    startTime: "2013-2-2",
    endTime: "2013-2-6",
    number: 1,
  },

  {
    task: "write the JS",
    type: "coding",
    startTime: "2013-2-1",
    endTime: "2013-2-6",
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    task: "eat",
    type: "celebration",
    startTime: "2013-2-8",
    endTime: "2013-2-13",
    number: 0,
  },

  {
    task: "crying",
    type: "celebration",
    startTime: "2013-2-13",
    endTime: "2013-2-16",
    number: 0,
  },
];

//array sorting
items.sort((a, b) => {
  return (
    a.number - b.number || Date.parse(b.startTime) - Date.parse(a.startTime)
  );
});

//here create new array and add index for every label
var taskArray = [];
var stack = [];
items.map((e) => {
  var lane = stack.findIndex(
    (s) => s.endTime <= e.startTime && s.startTime < e.startTime
  );

  var yIndex = lane === -1 ? stack.length : lane;
  taskArray.push({
    ...e,
    yIndex,
  });
  stack[yIndex] = e;
});

//here hardcoded grouping based on index and type
var nRows = d3.max(taskArray, (d) =>
  d.type === "celebration" ? d.yIndex + 1 : null
);

//here hardcoded grouping based on index and type
var nRows2 = d3.max(taskArray, (d) =>
  d.type === "development" ? (d.yIndex = d.yIndex + 1 + nRows) : null
);

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var timeScale = d3.time
  .scale()
  .domain([
    d3.min(taskArray, function(d) {
      return dateFormat.parse(d.startTime);
    }),
    d3.max(taskArray, function(d) {
      return dateFormat.parse(d.endTime);
    }),
  ])
  .range([0, w - 150]);

var categories = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
  categories.push(taskArray[i].type);
}

var catsUnfiltered = categories; //for vert labels

categories = checkUnique(categories);

makeGant(taskArray, w, h);

function makeGant(tasks, pageWidth, pageHeight) {
  var barHeight = 20;
  var gap = barHeight + 4;
  var topPadding = 75;
  var sidePadding = 75;

  var colorScale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, categories.length])
    .range(["#00B9FA", "#F95002"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

  makeGrid(sidePadding, topPadding, pageWidth, pageHeight);
  drawRects(
    tasks,
    gap,
    topPadding,
    sidePadding,
    barHeight,
    colorScale,
    pageWidth,
    pageHeight
  );
  vertLabels(gap, topPadding, sidePadding, barHeight, colorScale);
}

function drawRects(
  theArray,
  theGap,
  theTopPad,
  theSidePad,
  theBarHeight,
  theColorScale,
  w,
  h
) {
  svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(theArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d.yIndex * theGap + theTopPad - 2;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return w - theSidePad / 2;
    })
    .attr("height", theGap)
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (d.type == categories[i]) {
          return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
        }
      }
    })
    .attr("opacity", 0.2);

  var rectangles = svg.append("g").selectAll("rect").data(theArray).enter();

  rectangles
    .append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 3)
    .attr("ry", 3)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)) + theSidePad;
    })
    //here draw milestones depend on index
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d.yIndex * theGap + theTopPad;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return (
        timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.endTime)) -
        timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime))
      );
    })
    .attr("height", theBarHeight)
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (d.type == categories[i]) {
          return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
        }
      }
    });

  rectangles
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.task;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return (
        (timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.endTime)) -
          timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime))) /
        2 +
        timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)) +
        theSidePad
      );
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d.yIndex * theGap + 14 + theTopPad;
    })
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("text-height", theBarHeight)
    .attr("fill", "#fff");
}

function makeGrid(theSidePad, theTopPad, w, h) {
  var xAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(timeScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickSize(-h + theTopPad + 20, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b"));

  var grid = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + theSidePad + ", " + (h - 50) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("dy", "1em");
}

function vertLabels(
  theGap,
  theTopPad,
  theSidePad,
  theBarHeight,
  theColorScale
) {
  var numOccurances = new Array();
  var prevGap = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    numOccurances[i] = [categories[i], getCount(categories[i], catsUnfiltered)];
  }

  var axisText = svg
    .append("g") //without doing this, impossible to put grid lines behind text
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(numOccurances)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      if (i > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          prevGap += numOccurances[i - 1][1];
          // console.log(prevGap);
          return (d[1] * theGap) / 2 + prevGap * theGap + theTopPad;
        }
      } else {
        return (d[1] * theGap) / 2 + theTopPad;
      }
    })
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("text-height", 14)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (d[0] == categories[i]) {
          //  console.log("true!");
          return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i)).darker();
        }
      }
    });
}

//from this stackexchange question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890203/unique-for-arrays-in-javascript
function checkUnique(arr) {
  var hash = {},
    result = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
    if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
      //it works with objects! in FF, at least
      hash[arr[i]] = true;
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//from this stackexchange question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227981/count-how-many-strings-in-an-array-have-duplicates-in-the-same-array
function getCounts(arr) {
  var i = arr.length, // var to loop over
    obj = {}; // obj to store results
  while (i) obj[arr[--i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1; // count occurrences
  return obj;
}

// get specific from everything
function getCount(word, arr) {
  return getCounts(arr)[word] || 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.svg {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  opacity: 0.3;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="svg"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a runnable [mre]. 400 lines of javascript is a lot to ask us to parse, if your question is only about a small part of it! Also, please give us some pointers as to what you mean by "grouping labels by type"

Comment: You seem to be confused about when to use vanilla JS and when to use d3JS. Using `style` and `innerHtml` is not necessary any more. You also need to make sure you read the [d3 v3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/) and not the later ones. For example, the parameter of `.on("mouseover"` in d3 is `d`, the datum that you tried to fetch using `d3.select(this).data()[0].name`, you can just replace by `d.name`

Comment: Ruben you are right. I'm just started using D3 and I'm a bit lost. Thanks for your suggestions. The source code is so long because I want u to see the whole app. I think it will be easier for u to understand what I mean. <br/> Here is the place where I need some help <br/>  `var nRows = d3.max(taskArray, (d) =>
  d.type === "celebration" ? d.yIndex + 1 : null
);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can massively simplify your code, while making it dynamic. Some pointers in addition to the comments I left

1. Just parse your date objects ASAP, instead of doing it every time you need them;
2. Use [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_nest) to group the categories;
3. Don't iterate over the categories to get the index for colouring, just use the second function argument `(d, i)`;
4. Draw one `g` element per category, one `rect.background` within the `g`, and the tasks that fit that category as well. That way, you can remove categories extremely easily, it makes it much easier to calculate position, and you need to set the fill colours only once.

Let me know if you have any questions

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 400;

var svg = d3
  .select(".svg")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("class", "svg");

//main array
var items = [{
    task: "conceptualize",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-1-28", //year/month/day
    endTime: "2013-2-1",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "sketch",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-2-6",
    endTime: "2013-2-9",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "color profiles",
    type: "development",
    startTime: "2013-2-6",
    endTime: "2013-2-9",
    number: 2,
  },

  {
    task: "HTML",
    type: "coding",
    startTime: "2013-2-2",
    endTime: "2013-2-6",
    number: 1,
  },

  {
    task: "write the JS",
    type: "coding",
    startTime: "2013-2-1",
    endTime: "2013-2-6",
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    task: "eat",
    type: "celebration",
    startTime: "2013-2-8",
    endTime: "2013-2-13",
    number: 0,
  },

  {
    task: "crying",
    type: "celebration",
    startTime: "2013-2-13",
    endTime: "2013-2-16",
    number: 0,
  },
];

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

items.forEach((e) => {
  e.startTime = dateFormat.parse(e.startTime);
  e.endTime = dateFormat.parse(e.endTime);
});

// Use d3.nest to group the items based on the category
// https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_nest
// You can use .sortKeys to sort by key, for example
var categories = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.type)
  .sortValues((a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime)
  .rollup(function(events) {
    // Here, we see if we can apply some useful logic
    // In this case, we search for overlapping events so they can be placed
    // in different lanes
    events.forEach(function(e, i) {
      // Look only at the preceding events
      // Remember that the events have been sorted already
      const overlappingEvents = events.slice(0, i)
        .filter(other => other.endTime > e.startTime);
      
      if(overlappingEvents.length > 0) {
        e.level = d3.max(overlappingEvents, e => e.level) + 1;
      } else {
        e.level = 0;
      }
    });
    return events;
  })
  .entries(items);

// Set for each category the required number of lanes
let offset = 0;
categories.forEach(c => {
  c.lanes = d3.max(c.values, d => d.level) + 1;
  c.offset = offset;
  offset += c.lanes;
});

var timeScale = d3.time
  .scale()
  .domain([
    d3.min(items, d => d.startTime),
    d3.max(items, d => d.endTime)
  ])
  .range([0, w - 150]);

makeGant(categories, w, h);

function makeGant(categories, pageWidth, pageHeight) {
  var barHeight = 20;
  var gap = barHeight + 4;
  var topPadding = 75;
  var sidePadding = 75;

  var colorScale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, categories.length])
    .range(["#00B9FA", "#F95002"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

  makeGrid(sidePadding, topPadding, pageWidth, pageHeight);
  drawRects(
    categories,
    gap,
    topPadding,
    sidePadding,
    barHeight,
    colorScale,
    pageWidth,
    pageHeight
  );
  vertLabels(gap, topPadding, sidePadding, barHeight, colorScale);
}

function drawRects(
  categories,
  theGap,
  theTopPad,
  theSidePad,
  theBarHeight,
  theColorScale,
  w,
  h
) {
  const categoryGroups = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(categories)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      // Take the preceding categories and sum their required number of levels
      return `translate(0, ${d.offset * theGap + theTopPad - 2})`;
    })
    // All children inherit this attribute
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
    })

  // Just draw one rectangle for all lanes of this category
  categoryGroups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return w - theSidePad / 2;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return theGap * d.lanes;
    })
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("opacity", 0.2);

  //
  var rectangles = categoryGroups
    .selectAll(".task")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter();

  rectangles
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "task")
    .attr("rx", 3)
    .attr("ry", 3)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return timeScale(d.startTime) + theSidePad;
    })
    //here draw milestones depend on index
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d.level * theGap;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return timeScale(d.endTime) - timeScale(d.startTime);
    })
    .attr("height", theBarHeight)
    .attr("stroke", "none");

  rectangles
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.task;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return (timeScale(d.endTime) - timeScale(d.startTime)) / 2 +
        timeScale(d.startTime) + theSidePad;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d.level * theGap + 14;
    })
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("text-height", theBarHeight)
    .attr("fill", "#fff");
}

function makeGrid(theSidePad, theTopPad, w, h) {
  var xAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(timeScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickSize(-h + theTopPad + 20, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b"));

  var grid = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + theSidePad + ", " + (h - 50) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("dy", "1em");
}

function vertLabels(
  theGap,
  theTopPad,
  theSidePad,
  theBarHeight,
  theColorScale
) {
  var axisText = svg
    .append("g") //without doing this, impossible to put grid lines behind text
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(categories) // one label per category
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    })
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return (d.offset + d.lanes / 2) * theGap + theTopPad;
    })
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("text-height", 14)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i)).darker();
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.svg {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  opacity: 0.3;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="svg"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```